# Save Image of Google map to be loaded offline

Tags: google-maps, ipad, mobile, ionic-framework

I am using Google maps in an Ionic application (which connects to NodeJS/Express) for ipad.

In the app, I am displaying markers for the addresses provided by the user. My use case is such that users need to view the google map with markers when they are offline. These are primarily field users who do not have access to internet when on the field.

The approach I was thinking was to have users launch the google maps with markers set, in the ionic app (when they are connected to the internet) and provide a save button. Once they click on the save button, we somehow save an image/screenshot of the maps view on the device.

When the user opens the map while offline we load this image instead.

What would be the best way to save the image of the map shown in a Ionic app? Is there another approach which I should be looking at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**option 1**: I think here you can use Google Static Maps api which returns image files you can call this api when user clicks on save button (*obviously when you have internet connection*), and cache the image locally. Just go through the [Google Static Maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro)

**option 2:** I don't prefer this but worst case if nothing works for you just take a screen shot of the user's screen and save that image. Here is the cordova plugin to take screenshots [cordova-screenshot](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot)

Happy coding :)